# Make syncronous file read in javascript

Tags: javascript, file, cordova

i'm trying to read some files with **Phonegap** and put them in a array. My array has 2 elements per row, `file name` and `file content`.

I now do this:

```
var sharedContent = "";

function populateArray() {

    for (i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
        var singleFile = {};
        singleFile.name = entries[i].name;
        entries[i].file(fileSuccess, fileFail);
        singleFile.content = sharedContent;
        fileArray.push(singleFile);
    }
}

function fileSuccess(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
        sharedContent = evt.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsText(file);
}

var fileFail = function (error) {
    alert(error.code);
}
```

This works but **fileSuccess** is trigghered after the for cycle and the **sharedContent** variable is still empty.
How can i make that work? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do that. Since it's Asynchronous, everything has to happen inside `onload` for success. `var sharedContent`'s changes will only be visible inside your `onload` function, unless you `setTimeout()` or do something else Asynchronous, which I don't recommend.

Comment: thank you for your answer! So.. can i read file content inside the for cycle in some way? Like waiting for function completition or return the read value in some way

Comment: No, when you define `var sharedContent = "";` it's technologically at a different time than when the file in `FileReader` loads. Your JavaScript page is read when the HTML page loads. It is not read again, unless an Event occurs. In this case the Event should be `onload`, when the file loads successfully. So, when you test `var sharedContend` outside of the Event, you are really testing it before the Event occurs.